# Convert STRING_AGG to FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with nested selects. I wrote this query in SQL Server 2017 and now I must convert this to use in SQL Server 2014. As I know that `STRING_AGG` must convert to `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`, I tried some type of queries but I can't find the answer.

Original working query in SQL Server 2017 is:

```
SELECT filesanadrow, STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),result.tarafhesabsharh), ' ; ') AS tarafhesabha
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT k.row AS filesanadrow, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.tarafhesabsharh) AS tarafhesabsharh
FROM filesanad AS k INNER JOIN tarafhesab AS t ON k.row = t.filesanadrow) AS result
GROUP BY filesanadrow
```

And then `STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),result.tarafhesabsharh), ' ; ')` must convert to FOR XML PATH and STUFF.

I tried this code:

```
SELECT filesanadrow,
STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + t2.tarafhesabsharh
from result t2 where t1.filesanadrow = t2.filesanadrow 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'') AS tarafhesabha
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT k.row AS filesanadrow, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.tarafhesabsharh) AS tarafhesabsharh
FROM filesanad AS k INNER JOIN tarafhesab AS t ON k.row = t.filesanadrow) AS result
GROUP BY filesanadrow
```

But SQL Server Returns:

> (Invalid object name 'result'. SQL2.sql 3 1 )

Also I tried:

```
SELECT filesanadrow,
STUFF((SELECT '; ' + name FROM result  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS tarafhesabha
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT k.row AS filesanadrow, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.tarafhesabsharh) AS tarafhesabsharh
FROM filesanad AS k INNER JOIN tarafhesab AS t ON k.row = t.filesanadrow) AS result
GROUP BY filesanadrow
```

But SQL Server returns:

> Invalid object name 'result'. SQL2.sql 2 1

And again I tried:

```
SELECT filesanadrow,
STUFF((SELECT '; ' + tarafhesabsharh FROM tarafhesab  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS tarafhesabha
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT k.row AS filesanadrow, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), t.tarafhesabsharh) AS tarafhesabsharh
FROM filesanad AS k INNER JOIN tarafhesab AS t ON k.row = t.filesanadrow) AS result
GROUP BY filesanadrow
```

But SQL Server goes to ***non stop running*** with this code.

How can I convert that query?

Comment: Create a UFD instead and use that UDF. There are a *lot* of duplicate questions that show how to do that. A faster and cleaner option would be to use a SQLCLR UDF instead of the XML PATH method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What is UFD? (Unique factorization domain) ???

Comment: @bsflasher in the context of a database : [User Defined Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [CROSS APPLY](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-difference-between-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-in-sql-server/) works a bit like the nested version of an `INNER JOIN`.

While an `OUTER APPLY` would be like the nested version of a `LEFT JOIN`.

So try this example:

> ```
> create table filesanad
> (
>  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>  [row] int
> );
>
> insert into filesanad values 
> (1),(1),(2),(2),(3)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> create table tarafhesab
> (
>  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>  filesanadrow int,
>  tarafhesabsharh varchar(30)
> );
>
> insert into tarafhesab 
> (filesanadrow, tarafhesabsharh) values
> (1,'foo'),(1,'bar'),
> (2,'buz');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- CROSS APPLY on a FOR XML
> -- 
> SELECT f.filesanadrow, ca.tarafhesabha
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT [row] AS filesanadrow
>     FROM filesanad
>     GROUP BY [row]
> ) f
> CROSS APPLY
> (
>     SELECT STUFF(q.x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS tarafhesabha
>     FROM
>     (
>         SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + t.tarafhesabsharh 
>         FROM tarafhesab AS t
>         WHERE t.filesanadrow = f.filesanadrow
>         FOR XML PATH(''), type
>     ) q(x)
>     WHERE q.x IS NOT NULL
> ) ca;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> filesanadrow | tarafhesabha
> -----------: | :-----------
>            1 |  bar; foo   
>            2 |  buz
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- OUTER APPLY on a FOR XML
> -- 
> SELECT f.filesanadrow, ca.tarafhesabha
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT [row] AS filesanadrow
>     FROM filesanad
>     GROUP BY [row]
> ) f
> OUTER APPLY
> (
>     SELECT STUFF(q.x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS tarafhesabha
>     FROM
>     (
>         SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + t.tarafhesabsharh 
>         FROM tarafhesab AS t
>         WHERE t.filesanadrow = f.filesanadrow
>         FOR XML PATH(''), type
>     ) q(x)
>     WHERE q.x IS NOT NULL
> ) ca;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> filesanadrow | tarafhesabha
> -----------: | :-----------
>            1 |  bar; foo   
>            2 |  buz        
>            3 | null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- nested query with a FOR XML
> -- 
> SELECT 
> f.[row] AS filesanadrow, 
> (
>     SELECT STUFF(q.x.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS tarafhesabha
>     FROM
>     (
>         SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + t.tarafhesabsharh 
>         FROM tarafhesab AS t
>         WHERE t.filesanadrow = f.[row]
>         FOR XML PATH(''), type
>     ) q(x)
>     WHERE q.x IS NOT NULL
> ) AS tarafhesabha
> FROM filesanad f
> GROUP BY f.[row]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> filesanadrow | tarafhesabha
> -----------: | :-----------
>            1 |  bar; foo   
>            2 |  buz        
>            3 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e488f803c32b4714907da82752236865)*

Comment: It is OK in SQL Server, Thanks. But unfortunately  I can't CROSS APPLY in Visual Studio DataSet Designer as it says : **The OUTER APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported**

Comment: @bsflasher Oh, I don't know that "DataSet Designer".  Does it support nested queries?  For example `select 'x' x, (select 'y') y;`.  Because `OUTER APPLY` and `CROSS APPLY` do basically something similar as a nested query.  Then try with putting the query used in the `APPLY` in a nested query.